# Hillshading all tiles by default in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hillshade

I've downloaded a zip of img files from the TN Lidar page, but see no useable tilemap to know which tiles I actually want to look at (the whole zip was over 4GB amd 600 tiles). I'm only wanting to look at terrain details, so just need to hillshade the tiles. I only seem to be able to choose one at a time and manually check off hillshade.

Is there a way to set styling for all layers I have loaded at once?